# EF Core 3.1 Migration Tool is failing because of a dependency on .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.1

I have a project that uses EF Core 3.1. The startup project is an Azure Function that is running using V3 and framework 3.1. The rest of the projects are class libraries that are .NET Standard 2.0 projects.

I am trying to generate a migration script for EF Core 3.1 and I am getting the following error from Azure DevOps

```
Starting: Run EF Core Migrations
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.163.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
dotnet ef migrations script --startup-project C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s/MyProject/MyProject.Function.WebApi/MyProject.Function.WebApi.csproj --output C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\a/16138/Migrations/SqlScript.sql --context $dbContext --idempotent --verbose --framework netcoreapp3.1
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\_temp\3930c14d-f779-4939-9748-dd2ab8c6baa0.cmd""
Using project 'C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s/MyProject/MyProject.Function.WebApi/MyProject.Function.WebApi.csproj'.
Using startup project 'C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s/MyProject/MyProject.Function.WebApi/MyProject.Function.WebApi.csproj'.
Writing 'C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s\MyProject\MyProject.Function.WebApi\obj\MyProject.Function.WebApi.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp74C6.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s/MyProject/MyProject.Function.WebApi/MyProject.Function.WebApi.csproj
Writing 'C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s\MyProject\MyProject.Function.WebApi\obj\MyProject.Function.WebApi.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp77C5.tmp;TargetFramework=netcoreapp3.1 /verbosity:quiet /nologo C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s/MyProject/MyProject.Function.WebApi/MyProject.Function.WebApi.csproj
Build started...

Build succeeded.
dotnet exec --depsfile C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s\MyProject\MyProject.Function.WebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.Function.WebApi.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.nuget\packages C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\3.1.1\dotnet-ef\3.1.1\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll migrations script --output C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\a/16138/Migrations/covImsSqlScript.sql --context $dbContext --idempotent --assembly C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s\MyProject\MyProject.Function.WebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.Function.WebApi.dll --startup-assembly C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s\MyProject\MyProject.Function.WebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProject.Function.WebApi.dll --project-dir C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s\MyProject\MyProject.Function.WebApi\ --language C# --working-dir C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\2\s --verbose --root-namespace MyProject.Function.WebApi
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.0 at [C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\_tool\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.1 at [C:\vstsagent\A6\_work\_tool\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win81-x64
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-2147450730'.
Finishing: Run EF Core Migrations
```

When I look into the folder of the tool that gets installed when you execute **dotnet.exe tool install dotnet-ef -g** I can see that there is a directory that is still referencing the framework 2.0, which is present on the command that dotnet ef migrations script run.

```
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\.dotnet\tools\.store\dotnet-ef\3.1.1\dotnet-ef\3.1.1\tools\netcoreapp3.1\any\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll
```

The only thing I can think of is that EF Core 3.1 needs .NET Core 2.0 to also be installed on the build server for it to work. However, that does not feel right.

Has anyone experienced something similar and did you manage to find a solution other than installing .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: This solution might help [https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18645](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18645)

Comment: Try a clean build.  The compiler doesn't recognize when Library changes so the intermediate object files are using Core2.0 instead of Core3.1.

Comment: The build is generated by the dotnet ef migrations script command. How do you instruct it to make a clean build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what was the issue. I was missing the --project parameter. However, once I put it I was getting the following error:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyProject.Function.WebApi.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'MyProject.Common', version: '1.0.0'
    path: 'MyProject.Common.dll'
```

It looks like the EF Core Migration Tool does not like a startup project that is an Azure Function Project. Since the migration project is .NET Standard what I did was to create a console project that does nothing (just a Program.CS with a Console.Writelne("")) and make it reference the project that contained the migrations and use it as my Startup Project. By doing that migrations are working fine.